# MVC3 request delay needed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, asynchronous, long-polling

I have a MVC3 application. I have to add a delay in one uri request. I know the simplest way to do is an sleep, but the application in production has a big number of request and i'm afraid that let the iis without threads to response to other request.

I'm looking at the async controller/action for the solution.

Is better for the iis thead pool to do the thread.sleep inside the "actionSync" method?

How can i solve this delay? Maybe an async action that calls a new Web Service that does the thread.sleep inside?

```
    AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();
    DelayService delayService = new DelayService();
    delayService.GetDelayCompleted += (sender, e) =>
    {
        AsyncManager.Parameters["result"] = e.Value;
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
    };
    newsService.GetDelayAsync(seconds);
```

In this case if i will deploy this web service to the same IIS that the mvc3 app affects the iis available threads for the mvc3 app? what if is deployed in a different application pool?

What can ido?

Comment: Why don't you do the delay client side?

Comment: i've already done but is a non secure method and is posible to avoid the delay or to send a request after the delay. My data are in continuos changes and before accept one request i have to ensure the delay is done, no more no less. In this way i have to accept requests in a delay range (my delay plus the connection delay) and is posible to reject slow connections. For example if my delay is 4 the min is 4 and the max maybe 7 for slow connections or mobile. To avoid hack intentions i have to reject less and more than 4 second and the best solution for me is to get the delay in the server.

Answer (score 0):

Can you consider using the new ASP.NET MVC 4 bits which were released by Microsoft?

If so, this might be a possible solution:

```
public class TestController : AsyncController {
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetData() {
        await Task.Delay(5000);

        return Content("Done");
    }
}
```